# Failure using "npm publish"

Tags: node.js, npm

I maintain the NPM package LintRoller:
  - https://npmjs.org/package/lintroller

Recently I've tried pushing a new version, but I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT response undefined  
npm ERR! Error: login error  
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:82:22) 
npm ERR!     at CouchLogin.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/couch-login/couch-login.js:177:14) n## Heading ##pm ERR!     at CouchLogin.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/couch-login/couch-login.js:159:46) 
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:129:22) 
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)  
npm ERR!  at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:873:14) 
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)  
npm ERR! at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:824:12) 
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)  
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16  
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:  
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>  
npm ERR! or email it to:  
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>  
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0  
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "publish"  
npm ERR! cwd /Users/arthurakay/www/PhantomLint  
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20  
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11  
npm ERR!   
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:  
npm ERR!     /Users/arthurakay/www/PhantomLint/npm-debug.log  
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

That is using "npm publish" from my Mac OSX (Mavericks) terminal.

This used to work... but it's been a few months since I tried. Has something changed? Or did I mysteriously loose some login credentials on my local machine?

Comment: Have you tried `npm login`?

Comment: FAIL. I had not... I never had to before, as far as I can remember. Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@robertklep Hit the nail on the head. *npm login* was the key, though I don't remember having to do that before. Kudos sir!

Comment: Don't blame yourself. NPM's error messages are just completely useless. It would not share with you what the server said, if its life dependent on it. On Windows, all I got is: `npm ERR! registry error parsing json`

Comment: If this doesn't work and you need to manually add your creds, this describes it here: [Failure using “npm publish”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911589/npm-publish-azure-artifacts/56285920#56285920).