# npm publish azure artifacts

Tags: npm, azure-devops, npm-publish

I'm trying to publish a **scoped package** to a private azure devops artifact feed.  I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/publish?view=azure-devops).  I have a project .npmrc with the following entries:

```
@my-scope:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/
@my-scope:always-auth=true
```

In my global user .npmrc I have the following entries:

```
prefix=/usr/local
strict-ssl=false
unsafe-perm=true
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken="my-real-token"
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/:username=${NPM_USERNAME}
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm registry/:_password="my-real-base64-token"
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/:email=${NPM_EMAIL}
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/:always-auth=true
@my-scope:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm registry/:_authToken="my-real-base64-token"
cafile=${NPM_CERT_LOCATION}
```

When I try: npm publish I get the following error:

```
Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/some-guid, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodcus1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
```

Based on previous posts I see that I might need to do npm login. Executing npm login gives me this error:

```
npm verb node v6.9.2
npm verb npm  v6.8.0
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-org/_packaging/my-feed/npm/registry/-/user/org.couchdb.user:my-username
```

[I looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335120/failure-using-npm-publish) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047595/azure-devops-artifacts-401-error-when-publishing-npm-extension) which seemed to be related.  However, neither of them worked.
I've tried: curl  and curl -u   which gave me the following error:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}%
```

I'v also tried with a proxy and a cert.  However, with the same results.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit old, not sure if you are still stuck, but for Windows you can use this npm package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-npm-auth`:

```
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth
vsts-npm-auth -config path-to-your\.npmrc
```

Here is a more complete article from Azure DevOps that walks you through setup, .npmrc and auth and publishing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows:

If you are developing on Linux or Mac, vsts-npm-auth is not supported and we recommend generating a token in the following manner for your $HOME/.npmrc
The Connect to feed dialog box generates an appropriately formatted token that you can place into your .npmrc file with a lifespan of 90 days.

1. From Azure Artifacts, select Connect to feed.
2. Select npm.
3. Select Generate npm credentials. Copy the credentials to add them to your user .npmrc file manually. For Windows this is in %USERPROFILE%.npmrc and can be useful if the above method doesn't work. For Linux it is in $HOME/.npmrc.

Comment: This worked for me, I had to delete the .npmrc file under %USERPROFILE% and then run npm install -g vsts-npm-auth